# Proper approach using RabbitMQ to store data?

Tags: php, laravel, rabbitmq, messagebroker

My service listens some queues on RabbitMQ. Reading one of them, I need to write data in database immediately until queue is not empty. If there are a lot of record in queue it comes as narrow spot in application between RabbitMQ and SQL Server.

How to handle this reading/writing proper? Now it looks as usual writing data in database, cause  RabbitMQ throws database with messages from queue.

Comment: Are you using Java?

Comment: I use PHP (Laravel)

Comment: Seems it is possible to configure queue, when handler can not read next message from queue still not finish current operation, right?

Comment: Or consumer(service), should ask queue with delay time?